# osSemaphore doesn't works but osMutex do

Tags: freertos, stm32cubeide

I'm working with freeRTOS on STM32CubeIDE and so I'm using cmsis os
I need to block the call to a function that uses the USB port. There are two task, with the same priority that could call the function.
I was trying to acomplish that with a binary semaphore and do:

```
  /* definition and creation of PublisherSemaphore */
  osSemaphoreStaticDef(PublisherSemaphore, &PublisherSemaphoreControlBlock);
  PublisherSemaphoreHandle = osSemaphoreCreate(osSemaphore(PublisherSemaphore), 1);
```

on task a:

```
printf("IMU esperando semafores.\r\n");
cant_sem = osSemaphoreWait(PublisherSemaphoreHandle, osWaitForever);
printf("IMU %d semafores.\r\n", cant_sem);
ret = rcl_publish(&IMU_pub, &IMU_msg, NULL);
osSemaphoreRelease(PublisherSemaphoreHandle);
```

on task b:

```
cant_sem = osSemaphoreWait(PublisherSemaphoreHandle, osWaitForever);
printf("ENCO %d semafores.\r\n", cant_sem);
ret = rcl_publish(&ENCO_pub, &ENCO_msg, NULL);
osSemaphoreRelease(PublisherSemaphoreHandle);
```

but the code hangs on osSemaphoreWait of task a (the first that is executed), it's likley some other call to osSemaforeWait was made.
Then I replace the semaphore to a mutex:

```
  /* definition and creation of Publish_Mutex */
  osMutexDef(Publish_Mutex);
  Publish_MutexHandle = osMutexCreate(osMutex(Publish_Mutex));
```

Task a:

```
// Mutex to ensure one publisher acces to USB at a time
osMutexWait(Publish_MutexHandle, osWaitForever);
ret = rcl_publish(&ENCO_pub, &ENCO_msg, NULL);
osMutexRelease(Publish_MutexHandle);
```

Task b:

```
// Mutex to ensure one publisher acces to USB at a time
osMutexWait(Publish_MutexHandle, osWaitForever);
ret = rcl_publish(&IMU_pub, &IMU_msg, NULL);
osMutexRelease(Publish_MutexHandle);
```

and everithing is working with this. But I would like to know why osSemaphore approach doesn't work

Thank

Comment: The code you post seems compatible with example existing on [documentation](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/RTOS/html/group__CMSIS__RTOS__SemaphoreMgmt.html#ga97381e8e55cd47cec390bf57c96d6edb). The problem might be in the code you didn't show. Can you post a [MCVE]?